# Inter Thread Communication in Python using Condition object

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have written following code as a part of practicing inter thread communication in python using 'Condition' object

```
from threading import *
import time
c=Condition()

def sum():
    time.sleep(2)#if i comment this line then pgm waits,only sum() fun print stmt is executed
    c.acquire()
    print('here after this stms notify is called')
    c.notify()
    c.release()

def display():
    c.acquire()
    c.wait()
    print('display print is executing after notify')
    c.notify()
    c.release()

def show():
    c.acquire()
    c.wait()
    print('show print is executing after notify')
    c.release()

t2=Thread(target=display)
t3=Thread(target=show)
t1=Thread(target=sum)
t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
```

the pgm works fine but if i comment `time.sleep(2)` in `sum()` function then only print stmt of sum() function is executed and then waits. please tell me why this happens and why does this `time.sleep(2)` line really makes this difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `wait` method waits for another thread to awaken it by calling `notify`. This means we must call `wait` on threads *before* a call to `notify`.  What is happening is that `sum` with the sleep allows the `display` and `show` threads to call `wait`. At which point when the `sum` function calls `notify` one of them is woken up and can be called.

When the `time.sleep(2)` is not in the `sum` function, the `sum` function is acquiring `c` and running to completion before the `display` or `show` functions can get into the `wait` state. Note that this is a race condition, and it is feasible that on some occasions it might work as you want.

Also, by missing out the call to `notify` in the `show` method there is another potential race condition that means the `display` function is not called. This is because `notify` will wake up one thread by default. So this will only complete if the thread running `display` is woken up first.

In response to your comment about the difference between events and conditions. An event is a lightweight way of communicating between threads. One thread can signal an event and any number of threads can wait for the event. When the event is signalled all of the threads will wake up and execute. There is no lock involved. Events are typically not enough to protect state shared between threads.

With a condition variable a lock is used which means only one thread waiting on the condition variable is able to acquire the lock. This is good for protecting shared state.